How to combine two toolbars into one line
I'm trying to create a settings tab in my app and I would like to use the NavigationLink feature that SwiftUI provides. The core of my problem is that when I do this, NavigationLink creates it's own toolbar that is added on top of the toolbar I have in the view I'm navigating to. This makes logical sense, but I would like to combine these two toolbars to one so it doesn't look... well, crooked. Is it even possible?

In case it's possible, is there a way to make the NavigationTitle look the same as if the ScrollView is scrolled down like this?

My NavigationView is simple:
import SwiftUI

struct SettingsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section(header: Text("Current Weather")) {
                    NavigationLink(destination: DisplayedInformationSettingsView()) {
                        Text("Displayed Information")
                    }
                }
                
                Section(header: Text("Recommendations")) {
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Settings")
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    SettingsView()
}

And the view I'm navigating to looks like this:
struct DisplayedInformationSettingsView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = CurrentWeatherViewModel()
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section(header: Text("Displayed Information")) {
                    ForEach(viewModel.propertiesArray) { property in
                        HStack {
                            Toggle(isOn: Binding(
                                get: { property.info.isIncluded },
                                set: { newValue in
                                    toggleProperty(property, newValue: newValue)
                                }
                            )) {
                                HStack {
                                    Image(systemName: property.icon)
                                        .frame(width: 30)
                                    Text(property.name)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .foregroundColor(property.info.isIncluded ? .primary : .secondary)
                    }
                    .onMove(perform: move)
                }
                
            }
            
            .toolbar {
                EditButton()
                    .foregroundStyle(.primary)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Current Weather")
        }
    }
    
    private func move(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
        viewModel.propertiesArray.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
    }
    
    private func toggleProperty(_ property: WeatherProperty, newValue: Bool) {
        if let index = viewModel.propertiesArray.firstIndex(where: { $0.name == property.name }) {
            viewModel.propertiesArray[index].info.isIncluded = newValue
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    let viewModel = CurrentWeatherViewModel()
    return DisplayedInformationSettingsView(viewModel: viewModel)
}



DisplayedInformationSettingsView should not have its own NavigationView.

NavigationView is deprecated. You should use NavigationStack instead. If you make this change alone, you will no longer have double toolbars. But, as @Sweeper said, you only need one NavigationStack, the one in SettingsView. To change the size of the navigation title in the second view, use .toolbarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
